# Infinite dimensional representation of generators of the Lorentz group

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, poincare-symmetry

I was reading Schwichtenberg's "[Physics from Symmetry 2nd Edition](http://www.infis.ufu.br/%7Egerson/grupos/3%20-%20Great%20books/Physics%20from%20Symmetry.pdf)". In Section 3.7.11, there is the discussion on the infinite dimensional representations.
If we consider a transformation of the form:
\begin{equation}
    \Phi_a \rightarrow \Phi '_a = M_{ab}(\Lambda)\Phi_b
\end{equation}
where $M_{ab}(\Lambda)$ is some finite dimensional representation of the Lie algebra of the Lorentz group, and $\Phi_a$ is the object acted on by the transformation. However, because the coordinate is also transformed, the complete form should be:
\begin{equation}
    \Phi_a (x) \rightarrow \Phi '_a = M_{ab}(\Lambda)\Phi_b (\Lambda^{-1}x)
\end{equation}
Here, Schwichtenberg introduces the infinite dimensional representation since space of functions is infinite dimensions:
\begin{equation}
M_{\mu\nu}^{\text{inf}} = i(x^\mu\partial^\nu - x^\nu\partial^\mu)
\end{equation}
So to deal with $\Phi(\Lambda^{-1} x)$ we need this above representation. And then he went on saying that the transformation of the coordinates is given by:
\begin{equation}
\Phi(\Lambda^{-1} x) = e^{-i\frac{\omega^{\mu\nu}}{2}M_{\mu\nu}^{\text{inf}}}\Phi(x)
\end{equation}
This last step is what I don't get. How do you pull out the $\Lambda$ and get the exponent factor on the right side? I tried just Taylor expanding $\Phi(\Lambda^{-1} x)$ but that didn't work out for me.