# Lorentz transformation of four vector field

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, group-theory, representation-theory

For a 4-vector field $V^\mu (x)$, the Lorentz transformed 4-vector field $V'^\mu(x')$ can be written as

$$V'^\mu(x')={\Lambda^\mu} _\nu V^\nu(\Lambda^{-1}x')={\Lambda^\mu}_\nu V^\nu(x).$$

This can be seen as two transformations combined: one transformation on the 4-vector $V^\mu$ and another transformation on the coordinates $x$.

In the Physics from Symmetry [book](http://www.infis.ufu.br/%7Egerson/grupos/3%20-%20Great%20books/Physics%20from%20Symmetry.pdf), pg. 87-88, it was said that we can  use the infinite-dimensional representation of the Lorentz group

$$M_{\mu\nu}=i(x^\mu\partial^\nu-x^\nu\partial^\mu)$$ to find the transformation on the coordinates, i.e. $$V^\nu(\Lambda^{-1}x')=e^{-i\frac{w_{\mu\nu}}{2}M_{\mu\nu}}V(x),$$
where $w_{\mu\nu}$ are constants.

However, from the first equation, we can see that $V^\nu(\Lambda^{-1}x')=V^\nu(x)$. So the exponential factor seems redundant. What is wrong with my reasoning here?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/579694/infinite-dimensional-representation-of-generators-of-the-lorentz-group

Answer (score 1):

Well they are not exactly saying that. 
 Notice how they have masterfully used the arrow $\rightarrow$ instead of the equal sign to basically tell you "you figure it out".

The last equation, 3.251, reads:

$$ \Phi_a(x) \rightarrow \left ( \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\frac{\omega^{\mu\nu}}{2}M^{\mu\nu}} \right ) ^b_a \Phi_b(x).$$

Now, remember that you can write the Lorentz transformation matrix $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ in term of its generators $L_i$ (rotations) and $K_i$ (boosts) as:
$$ \boldsymbol{\Lambda} = \mathrm{e}^{\xi_i K_i + \theta_i L_i} = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\frac{\omega^{\mu\nu}}{2}M^{\mu\nu}}, $$
so the bit in the brackets is just a Lorentz transformation matrix.

So the first expression becomes:
$$ \Phi_a(x) \rightarrow \Lambda^b_a \,\Phi_b(x).$$

What does $\Phi_a(x)$ go to? Well it goes to $\Phi_a'(x')$:
$$ \Phi_a(x) \rightarrow  \color{red}{\Phi'_a(x') =} \Lambda^b_a \,\Phi_b(x).$$

This is the same expression that you start with in your question, with the substitution $\Phi_a \rightarrow V^\mu$.